# Class Inheritance from same Class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, magic-methods

I'm very new to python 2.7, and have been searching for an answer on this for a couple of hours so I figured I'd ask my first question here on overflow. I hope to one day add something to the community instead of lurking all the time >.<

I'm creating a project management tool where you define a nessicary **Base Task** under a **Project** and potentially other **sub tasks** inherited from the base task. I'm thinking for maximum flexibility it would be best to create a generic **Task Class** under a **Project Class**. When the user wants to create a sub task it inherits from the base task. I want to allocate one hour value to the base task which if there are no sub tasks is user defined, and if there are sub tasks is define by the sum of the hours defined by all the sub tasks.

So far this is what I have...:

```
class Task(self, superOBJ):
    #Define Tasks That Conform To SOW Here
    def __init__(self,cls,title):
        self.title=title
        self.description=""
        self.hours=None
    def Hours(self):
        if #NO SUBTASKS
            return self.hours
        else:
            return #SUM OF SUBTASKHOURS

    def SetHours(self,super,hours):
        self.hours=hours
```

This is where im stuck I have a few ideas but don't have the depth to see them through

So my question is what is a "good" way to handle the inheritance? Is there a magic method that could help out here?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to have `Task` inherit? Do you want to make it inherit `Project`?

Comment: That's not what class inheritance is for. I suggest you read up on what it's meant to be used for and how it works; [Wikipedia has a general overview.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) You want composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For the sake of convention*, I'm going to call the class for your "**Base Task**" `Task`, and the *base class of tasks* `BaseTask`

```
class BaseTask(object):
    '''change object to BaseProject whenever you figure out what your `Project`
    class should be, or if you need it at all'''

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.description=""

class Task(BaseTask):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(Task, self).__init__(title)
        self.subtasks = []
        self.default_hours = 1

    @property
    def hours(self):
        if len(self.subtasks) < 1:
            return self.default_hours
        return sum(subtask.hours for subtask in self.subtasks)

class SubTask(BaseTask):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(SubTask, self).__init__(title)
        self.hours = 0
```

That's basically what it should look like. You can make whatever changes you want to adapt it to your liking. In general, you should learn the difference between *inheritance* and *composition*. Here, both `Task` and `SubTask` inherit from `BaseTask`, but `Task` is *composed* of many `SubTask`s

Comment: The `Task` class looks good but it appears that the `SubTask` class is unnecessary because you can simply add a `Task` to the `subtask` list of another `Task`.  In fact, using the `SubTask` class is limiting because you cannot add a `SubTask` to another `SubTask`, whereas you can have multiple levels of sub-tasks using just the `Task` class.

Comment: So? It follows what his spec described, and if you're really a static typing weenie, you can make sure that subtasks only contains instances of `SubTask` with whatever method you prefer. This is just a skeleton, it can be refined to whatever the OP wanted.

Comment: I was hoping to only specify a single class and have unspecified depth to the number of sub tasks, in that a sub task may have its own subtask. Thank you all for your input!

Comment: Then you can just use the `Task` class I provided, and that will do everything! Just rename 'default_hours' to 'raw_hours' or something like that, and move title and description directly into `Task.__init__` and you're done! -- edit: didn't see bogatron's comment on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are suggesting that each sub-task should be an instance of a new class derived from `Task`.  If so, I recommend avoiding that approach.  What you are trying to create can easily be modeled by a tree of `Task` instances, where each task object holds a list (possibly empty) of child tasks (sub-tasks).  You can then calculate the time required for a task by recursively iterating through the child task lists to accumulate the times in the leaf nodes under the particular task (i.e., the `else` clause in your `Hours` method).

You may, at some point, have a good reason for defining a new class of tasks derived from `Task` but that should only be if they have some kind of special behavior relating to how e.g., their times are calculated.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I may have muddled a few programming terms, im fairly new to all this. But you got my basic idea that I want to have an unspecified number and depth of tasks. A Recursive function makes a lot of sense here!

Comment: The `Task` class that @forivall provided will do most of what you want.  You may want to add the individual task time to its constructor.  If you default that time to zero, then you can always return its own time *plus* the sum of its children's time. To create subtasks, just create a new `Task` object and do `task1.subtasks.append(task2)` (and you could similarly attach `task3` to `task2`).

Comment: Sweet, I'll give this a shot tommorow!